# Units conversion - Problem on re-converting rounded-off results back to original units

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, rounding, units-of-measurement

Checked all questions in **SO** that seemed related to my problem but could not find any answer that helps in my scenario.

I am developing an Asp.Net MVC 5 application with razor views and SQL Server as the database. I have a requirement to convert values from English to Metric units and back (Inches to Millimeter and back, Horsepower to Kilowatt and back etc.) on the go while user types in one of the unit value fields.

I achieve it by using UnitsNet conversion functions through ajax calls from UI on jQuery keyup events of the input fields. This works fine when user types in the values, and the converted values appears with several decimal points.

For example, **470 Hp (Horsepower) = 345.6844125 Kw (Kilowatts)**, and it correctly converts back to Hp.

However, when the values are rounded off, the conversion back to original value gives different result since the conversion happens on the rounded value.

I.e., **470 Hp = 345.68 Kw**. And when converting back to Hp, it comes as: **345.68 Kw = 469.99 Hp**.

The same happens when saving the values into database also. The column that saves the value is decimal (8,2) which obviously rounds off the values and gives this same results.

I would like to know your opinions on what would be the best way to handle this, to show consistent values on screen while converting and re-converting the values. Keeping all fields non-rounded, and also allowing maximum decimal points in the database minimizes this issue, but I am not sure if it is the correct way of handling this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Keep the most accurate form in the database and convert for display. That also means only round for display.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Here rounding is done for display only, but the re-conversion on the rounded display value gives the different result.

Comment: If you want to save the original values, why are you saying the rounded values?

Comment: The user has both fields (Hp and Kw for example) and can input on either of the fields, and the conversion (and re-conversion) should happen on-screen for the user. The results are consistent when not rounded, but he prefers to see the rounded values. I guess I may need to go with the all-non-rounded approach and convince the user why I can't round it off. Just wanted to check if there is any better approach.

Comment: I'd suggest only saving a new value if the user makes a change to the the fields that display those values, and only if the change (in the rounded displays) makes a difference.

Comment: The problem is your rounding, you can't expect to divide a number by another, round the result, and then multiply it again and get the same answer. `10/16=0.625` `0.625*16=10`,that much is true, but if you round to 2 decimal places `10/16=0.63` but `0.63*16=10.08!=10` once you round a number you lose accuracy, and you can't expect your system to "magically" know what accuracy was lost. `0.63` could have been any value `>=0.625` and `<0.635`, which is a big range to "guess" what it was for anyone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Larnu. I understand I cannot expect the same values after rounding and re-converting, but just wanted to know if there could be some way not to show the non-rounded values to the user on screen, may be by using some hidden fields to hold the actual results. Trying in that way, but thought to ask if someone has a better idea.